# Using the Menu, Back, Home buttons with AIR for Android, Flash CS6

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, button, air

I am looking to utilize and/or disable the hard "Home", "Back", "Menu" and "Search" buttons that are present on most Android phones and honestly don't know where to start.  Using Flash Professional CS6 AIR for Android.  I apologize if this is already answered somewhere but I cannot find any information on how to do this.  Thank you in advance for all the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you can stop the default behavior of the back, search, and menu soft keys but not Home:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/quick_start_as/quickstarts/qs_capturing_soft_keys.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, after doing some more checking from there I stumbled across another [link](http://www.grindheadgames.com/handling-button-air-android) with similar code that did the trick:



`code`(stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown);

protected function onKeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
 if( event.keyCode == Keyboard.BACK )
 {
  event.preventDefault();
  //handle the button press here.
 }
})